# What does "<phone name> is not included in this profile" mean in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to run a mobile app on a different test phone than I've been using, but though Xcode shows it in my list of targets, when I actually try to run it on the device I get the dreaded "The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile."

I'm using an "iPhone Developer" cert to sign the app, but when I try to install the "debug" profile onto the phone I get the message "'Dev iPhone 4' is not included in this profile".

What do I need to do to include the phone in the profile? I'm pretty new to all this provisioning stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you have to do is go onto the iOS Dev Center and add it into the list of devices you use to test with. Here is a link https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action It should give you step by step instructions on how to add the device, download the profile onto the device, and then you can use it after that. It's honestly a simple fix :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks--it looks like the device is already registered, but may have been wiped clean. Do I have to have admin permissions to download the device profile to the device again? I don't see any such option (only "Edit" and "Disable" but both buttons are disabled).

Comment: To answer my own question I think you do need admin permissions. Found an admit to take care of it for me. :)

Comment: no. You just follow the instructions, and it will generate a specific .<extension> file for you to download onto the device, and you just do that, and that should work :)